# R - plotting the three GEV distributions on one graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm very new to R and could do with some help on what I think should be a relatively simple problem...

So I have created some Gumbel, Frêchet and Weibull data using the "evd" package

ie. `weib <- rgev(n, loc=0, scale=1, shape = -0.5)`

and I am trying to plot all three on the same graph to display the GEV distributions, but cannot find how to do so. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
# Generate random data
library(evd)
gumb <- rgev(rnorm(100), loc=0, scale=1, shape = -0.5)
frec <- rgev(rnorm(100), loc=0, scale=1, shape = -0.5)
weib <- rgev(rnorm(100), loc=0, scale=1, shape = -0.5)
df <- data.frame(gumb, frec, weib)

# Transform data from wide to long format
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(df)

# Plot density using ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(value, color = variable)) +
    geom_density()
```

[image]